# How to find out who is using the physical console?

Tags: command-line, login, console, tty, username

I would like to use a script to find out the username - of the user who is currently on the **physical console** (who has command of the keyboard, mouse and graphical display)?

I do not just want to know who runs X (as the current console can be switched to another terminal and another user).

---

**To clarify:**
Commands like `w`, `who` etc. show who is logged at which terminal. This is simple. I would like to know, however, who owns currently the physical console (display, keyboard etc.). For example, if two users run displays :0 and :1, and I can switch between the displays with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>, I would like to know which user currently has the connection between his or her display and the actual, physical screen.

---

**One more clarification:**
 I am not interested in knowing *my own* username. I have a script, running as another user or root, that needs to know who uses the *physical* display. There can be several X sessions running by different users, some of them virtualized, some of them connected to a remote X server, but I am only interested in the one that is actually displaying output on the monitor.

---

**Yet another clarification:**
 Whatever the command is, the output must be different after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (switching to another virtual console).

Comment: Is this a self Q&A?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid I can't give you a specific answer (because I don't know the tech well), but I believe you can find it out using D-Bus and ConsoleKit.

For example, when I switch from X to a VT and back, I get this listening on `dbus-monitor`:

```
$ dbus-monitor --system | grep ConsoleKit
signal sender=:1.16 -> dest=(null destination) serial=19039 path=/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2; interface=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Session; member=ActiveChanged
signal sender=:1.16 -> dest=(null destination) serial=19040 path=/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Seat1; interface=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Seat; member=ActiveSessionChanged
signal sender=:1.16 -> dest=(null destination) serial=19041 path=/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2; interface=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Session; member=ActiveChanged
signal sender=:1.16 -> dest=(null destination) serial=19042 path=/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Seat1; interface=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Seat; member=ActiveSessionChanged
   string "/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2"
```

Specifically, you could use the [GetActiveSession](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html#Seat.GetActiveSession) method.  Here's how with `dbus-send` (may require `sudo`):

```
$ dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Seat1 org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Seat.GetActiveSession
```

Then, depending on your application, you'll want to check out the returned object's properties, which should be an object path to a [Session](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html#Session).

Comment: Very helpful, I think. When I switch sessions the reply switches correspondingly. In particular I could then enter the following command: `dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2 org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Session.GetUser` which replies with the current user-id. From there the library function getpwuid can get the username.

Comment: This is definitely the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

```
[geek@atremis ~]$ w

 20:02:02 up 2 days,  8:37,  3 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.00

USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT

geek     tty1     :0               Thu11    2days 35.11s  0.18s pam: gdm-passwo

geek     pts/0    athena           Fri22   21:04m  0.03s  0.03s -bash

geek     pts/1    blackbeauty      20:02    0.00s  0.14s  0.10s w

[geek@atremis ~]$
```

You can use the w command to see who is logged on. The idle time and what should tell you what is being run - in this case gdm indicates an active log in, and the idle time indicates the user has not been at the system in 2 days. Contrast this with the login from blackbeauty, which has a 0.00 idle time, which indicates its currently in use.

Comment: No, this only tells me -- as you wrote -- who is logged in at which *terminal*. To use with a script, I would like to know which user is owning the physical console (keyboard, display etc.)

Comment: P.S. idle time is also non-informative; I'm working on a script fiddling with a screensaver, but I want to know which user is running the screensaver *that is actually displayed*.

Comment: the TTY and 'what' might work here, you'd just need to extract the necessay bits.

Comment: Um, no, because it can run wherever (in background, on another X server, in a virtual machine)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways:

- `whoami`
- `w`
- `echo $USER`
- `logname`

Answer (score 0):

Another command is

```
whoami
```

It shows current logeed username