# Crontab issue with gedit

Tags: cron

I'd like to schedule a weekly backup with Crontab but I've never used it before so I wanted to start with a simple command to test it, like open a text file with gedit.

I followed this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

```
sudo crontab -e
```

I get my file in the terminal and I add this:

```
m h  dom mon dow  command
34 12    * * *    /usr/bin/gedit /home/KEN/Desktop/ImaTXT
```

It was 12: 32 when I saved and installed this new crontab:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
```

I checked that it was saved:

```
sudo crontab -l
```

Two minutes pass and nothing gets opened.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks Kevy, it worked.

Comment: Related: [Cron cannot run gnome-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202873/cron-cannot-run-gnome-terminal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have specified `$DISPLAY` environmental variable and user (may be *ken* in your case).

```
$ sudo crontab -e -u user

m h dom mon dow command
34 12 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/gedit /home/KEN/Desktop/ImaTXT
```

Comment: It is to start GUI application using cron.