# Crontab and C program that should be executed into a terminal window

Tags: gnome-terminal, cron, c

I want to create Cron job to run a compiled `.c` file. Let's say I have a file, called `program.c`, on my desktop. I compile it using `gcc program.c`, 
which creates `a.out` executable file.

I want to open a terminal at certain time via Cron and run `a.out` inside to show its output into the terminal. I've opened Crontab for editing - `crontab -e` - and I've tried:

```
30 *  * * * /home/username/Desktop/a.out /Desktop/a.out
```

and

```
30 *  * * * cd /home/username/Desktop/a.out && ./a.out
```

and

```
30 *  * * * /bin/sh /home/username/Desktop/a.out
```

and

```
30 *  * * * bash -c "exec /home/username/Desktop/a.out"
```

And nothing works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With a launcher for a terminal application, how can I keep the terminal open after the program is complete?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3359/with-a-launcher-for-a-terminal-application-how-can-i-keep-the-terminal-open-aft)

Comment: @George, I think it is not a duplication of the supposed question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the executable file generates an output file, or just modifies some things, the Cron job should be:

```
* * * * * /home/<user>/Desktop/a.out
```

<sup>If the paths inside the program are relative, their origin point should be properly defined, otherwise the output file will be placed, for an example, into the `$HOME` directory instead of `$HOME/Desktop`, where you suppose to be. This is a common mistake.</sup>

---

If the program doesn't write any output file and just generates some data within the [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams), you should [redirect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89416/201297) it to a file to see it into an appropriate place *(this part `2>&1` redirects and the error messages to stdout)*:

```
* * * * * /home/<user>/Desktop/a.out >> /home/<user>/Desktop/a.out.log 2>&1
```

While the stdout isn't redirected, Cron will sending [local mails](https://superuser.com/questions/306163/what-is-the-you-have-new-mail-message-in-linux-unix) to the user, unless this is overridden by setting the variable `MAILTO` in `crontab`:

```
MAILTO="my@custom.mail"
* * * * * /home/<user>/Desktop/a.out
```

- References: [How to detect error in cron jobs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418237/how-to-detect-error-in-cron-jobs) | [How do I make cron create cron.log?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966194/16-04-how-do-i-make-cron-create-cron-log-and-monitor-it-in-real-time)

---

To execute a GUI application via Cron is more difficult task, because Cron is not designed to work with GUI. [Few environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666729/6543935) should be exported and the best way to do that is to create an additional startup script. Here is an example how to do that within Ubuntu Unity/Gnome:

- Crate the script. Let's assume it is also located into the `~/Desktop` directory and is called `a-cron.sh`. Do nоt forget to make it executable - `chmod +x a-cron.sh`. The script should look as this:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  # Set the necessary environment variables - UBUNTU/UNITY/GNOME:
  export DISPLAY=$(w $(id -un) | awk 'NF > 7 && $2 ~ /tty[0-9]+/ {print $3; exit}')
  export GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=true
  export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(sed -zne 's/^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//p' /proc/`pgrep gnome-session -U $(id -u)`/environ)

  #Open new terminal and execute the script:
  /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x sh -c '/home/<user>/Desktop/a.out; exec bash'
  ```

  The part `exec bash` intends to keep the terminal window open after the execution of `a.out` - there are also other available approaches, that are described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3359/with-a-launcher-for-a-terminal-application-how-can-i-keep-the-terminal-open-aft).
- Now create user's Cron job - `crontab -e` - as this:

  ```
  * * * * * /home/<user>/Desktop/a-cron.sh > /home/<user>/Desktop/a-cron.log 2>&1</pre>
  ```

  Unlike as the above section, the log file plays different role here. The error messages from the execution of `a-cron.sh` shall be written inside `a-cron.log` - so if everything is okay it must be empty.
- Save and close `crontab` to apply the job. Wait about a minute to see the result.

References:

- [**This answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/911958/566421) is the main source of the third section, there could be found also the necessary [envvars](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) that shall be exported for desktop environments different from Unity/Gnome.
- In [**this question**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503028/how-to-launch-interactive-shell-script-in-bash-hourly-with-cron) OP uses root's Crontab, but this is not a good idea, because within this approach the ownership of some files and directories inside `/run/user/<uid>/dconf/` will be changed, thus a lot of errors will be generated.
- [Cron cannot run gnome-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202873/cron-cannot-run-gnome-terminal)
- [How to open one (or more) gnome-terminal window with few tabs, each with different profile, when start/reboot the computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953021/how-to-open-one-or-more-gnome-terminal-window-with-few-tabs-each-with-differe/953036#953036)
- [Open gnome terminal programmatically and execute commands after bashrc was executed](https://superuser.com/questions/198015/open-gnome-terminal-programmatically-and-execute-commands-after-bashrc-was-execu)
- [How to programmatically find the current value of DISPLAY when DISPLAY is unset? (for use in crontab)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744723/how-to-programmatically-find-the-current-value-of-display-when-display-is-unset) | [<del>How to get the display number I was assigned by X</del>](https://superuser.com/questions/647464/how-to-get-the-display-number-i-was-assigned-by-x)

Demo - I just created a simple C program (this is my first attempt) to check how all this works:

[image]

Comment: Ok, so how do I change it so that I can see the output?

Comment: @IDK, could you check please whether the output is placed within your home directory - `/home/username`? Btw, `* * * * *` in cronjobs means every minute.

Comment: I don't see any output in  my home dir

Comment: @IDK, but when you execute `./a.out` into a terminal there is a output file?

Comment: the output is on the terminal, I don't see more files getting created

Comment: Good work and +1! Minor nit pick on the Bash "timer" in your demo: You don't need to use command substitution and `echo -ne` to reposition the terminal cursor to the start of line if you have Bash's built-in `printf` command at your disposal: `printf '%(%c)T\r' -1`. This also saves some resources because the system doesn't have to pipe+fork+exec all the time.

Comment: Just for fun, where do you think stdout goes if it's not redirected?

Comment: I catch this :) @fkraiem : It goes to the user's local mailbox. Isn't it? I will update the answer, later today.

Comment: Yes (unless this is overridden by setting the `MAILTO` variable in the crontab file).